# IMC 2012 A6 - lemma 2

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

I have problem to understand the solution of Lemma 2 (exercise A6, 2012, IMC): https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2012s.pdf. Why "By continuity, it suffices to check the case where $\alpha=\arcsin{\frac{2}{d^2}}$ is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$"? Can you explain me?

Comment: You didn't link to the problem, and lemma 2 makes reference to the function $f$ from the problem.  In the future, please put everything necessary to understand your question in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number, and let $[x]$ denote the fractional part of $x$, so, for example, $[3.14]=0.14$.  Then it is a standard result that $\S={[n\alpha]\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in [0,1].  A continuous function which is constant on a dense set must be constant everywhere.

Now, take a periodic parameterization of the circumference of the circle with constant speed such that $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. Define $g(t)=f(\gamma(t))+f(\gamma(t+1/2))$.  The goal of the lemma is to show that this function is constant.  The strategy is to show that it is constant on a dense set of the form $S$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. Do you know how to proof the induction in this solution?

Comment: @Catala If you have a circle of radius $d>\sqrt{2}$, and you inscribe a rectangle of area $1$, what are the side lengths? What is the angle between two of the corners (relative to the center of the circle)?  Now use Lemma 1

Comment: The case when $\alpha=\beta$ is clear. But how to prove the step form $n-1$ to $n$?

Comment: You can rotate by $\alpha$ once.  Then you can rotate by $\alpha$ again.  And again.  And again.  And again.  Lemma 1 tells you that EVERY time you rotate by that specified angle, the sum of the values on the diameter remains constant.  Induction tells you that you will have an infinite set where this quantity is constant.  Since it is dense, continuity tells you that it is constant on the whole circle.

Comment: Okey, I have the last question: why may we take in Lemma 1 coordinates $A=(0,0)$ etc. ? We don't consider the cases when our figure is not parallel to $x$-axis.

Comment: They don’t explain it well, but when they say “we can choose coordinates” they don’t require that the axes in the new coordinate system are parallel to the axes in the original coordinate system. They are parallel to the sides of the rectangle, but the rectangle can be oriented however it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand all solution now :)